# Is it possible to make a function or class available to all views in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

The use case is as follows: We would like to have elements hidden or shown, based on the user's permissions.

The ideal way would be something like this:

```
<div if.bind="foo != bar && hasPermission('SOME_PERMISSION')"></div>
```

`hasPermission()` would in that case be a function that was automatically injected into all viewmodels.

Is that possible? I know we could use base classes for this, but we'd like to avoid that to stay as flexible as possible.

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066809/global-functions-in-aurelia

Comment: I saw that one, but it seems to be a different question. The accepted answer requires injecting it manually into each viewmodel, as far as i can see. That doesn't solve our use case.

Comment: This is something that is actively being designed/discussed. To make the progress on this more transparent I've opened an issue in templating:  https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/287

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to pay the price of a global function (global as in `window`), `import` it in your app-bootstrap file, like so:

#### has-permission.js

```js
export function hasPermission(permission) {
  return permission.id in user.permissions; // for example...
}
```

#### main.js

```js
import 'has-permission';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  // some bootstrapping code...
}
```

If the service you want to publish globally is a view, you can sidestep exposing it on the `window` and tell Aurelia's DI to make it available everywhere so you won't have to declare it in every dependent client.

To do so, pass its module ID in the [`FrameworkConfiguration#globalResources()`](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/api/class/FrameworkConfiguration) configuration function:

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .globalResources('my-kick-ass-view', 'my-awesome-converter');

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a service which deals with user permission, it can be injected in all your view-models.

```
export class UserPermissionService
{
     hasPermission(user, permission) 
     {
         return false;
     }
}

@inject(UserPermissionService)
export class Users {  
  userPermissionService;
  constructor(userPermissionService) {
    this.userPermissionService = userPermissionService;
    ...
  }
  hasPermission(user, p) 
  { 
     return this.userPermissionService.hasPermission(user, p);
  }
}
```

If you still don't like this, other options are:

- a value converter http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/binding/1.0.0-beta.1.2.1/doc/article/binding-value-converters
- a custom attribute (similar to `if` it will hide the element)
  http://www.foursails.co/blog/custom-attributes-part-1/

depending on what you need, both can use the UserPermissionService singleton from above

Comment: I know I can inject it that way, but I would like it to be available everywhere automatically, like the value converters are.

We also considered using a value converter, but that would give us less flexibility than using a method like in my example.

Our initial approach was creating a customised version of Aurelia's `if` attribute. That worked until the latest version of Aurelia. It seems that you can no longer have multiple attributes that are a `@templateController` on the same element.

Comment: could you please detail a bit why value converter give you less flexibility? no matter which way you hide the HTML element (converter, attribute, etc), you still need something like a service which is aware of current user and checks permission. 
I see element hiding and checking for permission separate responsibilities. Instead of hiding, in other parts of your app, you will might want to represent user permission in a different way, so you will still need a shared logic for user permission

Comment: We're giving this a go over here: https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-permissions/wiki/RFC:-Permissions. It's not done yet, but perhaps you would like to help, seeing how you seem to share the same interest. You can find us over at [gitter](https://gitter.im/SpoonX/Dev)

Answer (score -1):

Add a .js file in your folder, with export function
ex: utility.js

```
export function hasPermission(permission) {
     return true/false;
 };
```

import the function in view-model

```
import {hasPermission} from 'utility';
export class MyClass{
   constructor(){
         this.hasPermission = hasPermission;
        }
 }
```

view.html

```
 <div if.bind="foo != bar && hasPermission('SOME_PERMISSION')"></div>
```

Comment: The question is how to do this without having to inject it into every view-model manually.